# Call Unlock screen to authenticate. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, basic-authentication, unlock

I am developing an app for the iPhone and I want to make sure that it is the owner of the phone who is accessing the app. I had the idea of calling the unlock screen and have the user put in his pin when the app is opened. Is there any way to call the unlock screen and have a response back (true/false) that will let me know if the correct pin was entered?

Comment: No, but in iOS 8 you can use the fingerprint sensor for authentication. When the user unlocks his phone he already authenticated himself, so why ask him for a pin? If you still want this feature, you can ask the user for a pin the first time your apps starts and then always ask for that pin, whenever the app is launched.

Comment: As JoJoe says, this is now possible on iOS 8.  However, I would strongly advise against it: it's a pain in the ass for the user.  You should only implement extra security if the data you're protecting is extremely valuable (eg, a banking app).